# How to deploy EJB project and JPA project in EAR project

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I create 2 projects one is EJB and one is JPA. JPA project define entities classes, and persistent.xml. EBJ project import JPA project, I defined EJB session bean to connect database by entity manager. please refer below image for details. But when running on Jboss 7, error happend.

[image]

```
03:23:59,546 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."TestApps.ear"."TestEJB.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."TestApps.ear"."TestEJB.jar".POST_MODULE: Failed to p
rocess phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "TestEJB.jar" of deployment "TestApps.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class com.ejb.services.LotUpdatManagerBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.TestApps.ear.TestEJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/model/LotUpdates
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.model.LotUpdates from [Module "deployment.TestApps.ear.TestEJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        ... 15 more

03:23:59,762 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "TestApps.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"TestApps.ear\".\"TestEJB.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartExce
ption in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"TestApps.ear\".\"TestEJB.jar\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"TestEJB.jar\" of deployment \"TestApps.ear\""}}
03:23:59,765 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment TestEJB.jar in 2ms
03:23:59,767 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment TestApps.ear in 4ms
03:23:59,768 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."TestApps.ear"."TestEJB.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."TestApps.ear"."TestEJB.jar".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "TestE
JB.jar" of deployment "TestApps.ear"
```

I'm failed. Anyone can correct me, Show me the way to deploy(jpa project and ejb project in same ear).

Comment: By `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.model.LotUpdates from [Module "deployment.TestApps.ear.TestEJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]` Jboss is telling you that the class `LotUpdates` is expected to be found inside the `TestEJB.jar` which itself is located inside the `TestApps.ear`. May i ask on how you build your ear? (Say you use maven any `/src/test/java` classes wont be packed to your Jars and thatfore remain missing in your ear too).

Comment: I've used export ear function of eclipse. My ear file after exported what has this structure: ear(lib + ejb jar). lib store jpa jar. It's same structure with above image.

Comment: I did not use maven. Just use default ant build in eclipse. As I see, ejb classes cannot load/found jpa classes. With your experience, one project for jpa, another one for ebj. Both of them packaged in ear, how do you do? What is correct structure in ear?

Comment: Please excuse i was on a similar question and got confused - forget i requested Maven information since you obviously dont use it at all ;)

Comment: Even thus it wont solve your problem i will have to provide a answer so i can format a little better

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 potential options:

- if you `TestJpa.jar` is in `ear\lib` folder it should be visible by default in ejb module (ensure that EAR is in `6.0` version)
- manually add via `Deployment Assembly` in EJB project, the JPA project - should result in changes in the manifest file for EJB module.

If you correctly configure it, using either way you should see the JPA project in the `EJB Module > EAR Libraries` in Eclipse, without need to add it as project in the Build Path

Answer (score 0):

As follow up to our discussion in the comments i provide this "answer" as a first hook on what could possible have gone wrong.

**Regarding the EAR structure**
The structure of the package types EAR, WAR and JAR are well defined and must be followed to generate enterprise archives (EARs) that later will run on application servers like JBoss.

You will find any required information on packaging under https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html (Note this is for Java EE 6).

Basicially thats the way to go and i wont be able to help you much more :(

But as requested in the comments i will try to point out some especially important points were linking happens and must be absolutly correct according to the above packaging conventions (i can tell you right away that our JPA-Modules for example are located in the lib-folder as well).

So if i open one of our (working) EARs i will see the following content inside it:

- lib
- META-INF
- our-ejb-part.jar
- our-website-application.war
- our-webservice-application.war

Our `ejb-part.jar` for example does not contain any Java code at all. It however contains a `META-INF` folder with descriptors such as **`ejb-jar.xml`** and some propertie-files under a `properties` folder as well. It also defines the classpath inside the **`MANIFEST.MF`**. (I havent worked with JBoss for years - we currently use IBM Websphere hence we have -bnd.xml/-ext.xml deployment descriptors located in the META-INF folder as well ... i am not aware if Jboss needs similar deployment informations). There is nothing more to see here.

Forget about the two Web-Modules for now- you dont seem to have any web-part in the form of a .war file (which itself must follow certain package requirements as defined in the oracle documentation).

But Note that if you have ANY EJB- or WEB-Modules they must be listed in the **application.xml** file located in the META-INF file (not the META-INF folder of the ejb but in the META-INF folder of the EAR located on the same level as `/lib`, `/our-ejb-part.jar`, etc.). Also note that inside that META-INF directory we again have the two Websphere deployment descriptors as well as a empty MANIFEST.MF).

Finally we have the `lib` folder that contains all of our EAR-Dependencies (and most of the Web-Part dependencies) are located at. That is the location we keep our JPA-, Commons-, Service-, Service-Implementations-, etc. Modules of a component (rather than having them inside the `ejb-part.jar` ... but i cant consider if this is a good practise).

So comming back to your situation there could be lots of things going wrong - i recommend you add a print-screen of the contents of your final *.ear file rather than the above eclipse view to probably get further advices. The main problem of that eclipse view is  that at least i dont know how exactly your final .ear file will look like (There is for example only the `WEB-INF` folder with the `application.xml` located under `EAR Content`.

Sorry i wont be a help from here on since i dont have any JBoss knowledge (the log may imply whats wrong on a even more detailed level than i can interpret ... i currently just know your EAR likely wont contain the class `LotUpdates` or it may be there but isnt added to the classpath properly)

Answer (score 0):

I did the same with eclipse on Ubuntu. EAR file contain ejb.jar and jpa.jar which jpa.jar is in *.ear/lib/ . Jboss 7 can deployed the ear packed. I think the root cause is jpa classes are built and packaged in jpa.jar, so that ejb.jar can load its.

Comment: Now, I'm trying to remote ejb within error. I search many examples on internet but still unlucky. javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory . I'm missing what?

Comment: You should post it as new question as it is not connected to the one you asked.